# Pulling DOM content as jQuery object from $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As part of a jQuery plugin, a strange object format is pulled using `$.get()`, meaning that DOM traversal isn't possible in any of the post-function hooks:

```
$.get($href)
.done(function(){
  $linkClicked.addClass('active')
})
.fail(function(){
  $.get(settings.errorUrl, function(){
    $('.main-navigation .active').removeClass('active')
  })

})
.always(function(data){

  // The below line does not work correctly
  $(settings.target).hide().html( $(data).children(settings.target).html() ).fadeIn('fast')

})
```

If somebody could lend a hand, that'd be great. Many thanks.

Comment: `var whatYouNeed = $('#yourId').val();`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do like this:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
 var container = $('<div />').html(data);
 var contentYouNeed =  container.find('#ajaxID').html();
});
```

As you can see on the document [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), The returned `data` by 
`jQuery.get()` is a PlainObject or a String.

> **data**
>    Type: **[PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)** or **[String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String)** 
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

To retrieve the contents from this object, you put this data in a  `<div>` object like this.

```
 var container = $('<div />').html(data);
```

And you can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the content.

```
var contentYouNeed =  container.find('#ajaxID').html();
```

Comment: Please see revision of question

Answer (score 1):

No no no no. You don't use `regex` for parsing HTML please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Also, to solve you problem use [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): `$("#yourID").html()`

Comment: Well-aware of this. The HTML in question is the data returned from a $.get() response. Unless you know of a way in which to convert this response data to a jQuery object?

Comment: @user2568056 `$.get().done(function (html) { var $html = $(html) /* you can now use this like a jQuery collection in the document */`

Comment: Please see revision of question

Answer (score 0):

So the response is always *one* div element? In that case it's just a matter of grabbing the contents of it. No matter what the ID and attributes are.

```
$.get('ajax/call.php', function(data) {
    var contents = $(data).html();
});
```

Comment: Please see revision of question